# Flow loop iteration issue

Tags: visual-workflow, automation

I have two Loop elements: parent and child loops in a flow. I'm trying to break out of the child loop once I find a match and go back to the parent loop.

Pretty much like this in apex:

```
List<customObj> cObjList = [SELECT Id, Industry FROM customObj];
for(Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, Account.Industry FROM Opportunity]){
    for(customObj co : cObjList){
        if(co.Industry == opp.Account.Industry){
            //do something
            break; //go to the next iteration in the parent loop
        }
    }
}
```

In the flow, I'm able to break out of the child loop and start from the next iteration of the parent loop. However, the child loop DOES NOT start from the beginning.

[image]

Also, once I find the successful match in child loop,

- perform some business logic
- empty the collection used for child loop
- connect it to the beginning of the parent loop (here, the collection will be reassigned with actual records)

*this is based on some online suggestion*

Is there a workaround for this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. Loops don't start/restart that way; there's no equivalent to `break` in flow loops. Instead, use the [Collection Filter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_filter.htm&type=5) to find the matching child record(s) so you can then finish the loop so it will restart on the next pass.

Edit: I realized I meant to say that if you connect the "for-each" part through a decision to the "parent" loop, that means you're now in a third loop, like this (Apex):

```
for(Parent parent: parentRecords) {
  for(Child child: childRecords) {
    if(matchChild(parent, child)) {
      for(Parent parent2: parentRecords) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You need to connect the "after last item" path to the parent loop in order to avoid this problem.

> connect it to the beginning of the parent loop (here, the collection will be reassigned with actual records)

This is your problem. You can empty the collection, but the child loop needs to connect to itself, and the "after last item" path should go to the parent loop.

Here's a quick visual for what I believe should work.

[image: A flow, looping over child records filtered by the parent]

Comment: I tried this already but the flow acts the same. Guess I'll have to let the child loop run its full record count but have some decision to see if match found at some point. Really wish there were ```break``` and ```continue``` features

Comment: @apz I added a small example. Compare what you've done to this, let's see if we can spot any differences.

Comment: Let me give some more context, the child records are basically 15 metadata records which are sorted by a custom field called Rank. Once the parent loop starts, I'm trying to get into these mdt records and find a match with a Decision element with 7 different paths. So with your collection filter mechanism, am I creating 7 different collection filters and keep checking them? Sorry for my noobness

Comment: @apz You could probably use a Formula to keep it down to a single collection filter.